# Where is the goapp binary?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, installation

I'm very confused on the set up of Golang.

I downloaded `go_appengine_sdk_darwin_amd64-1.9.48.zip`.

When I unpacked the zip file, I could not find the `goapp` binary.

It looks like goapp is a binary used to run a local GAE server but I'm a newb to golang and just following the tutorial:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/getting-started/creating-guestbook#building_and_running_locally

```
$ ls go/bin/    

total 54560  
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 bryan  staff   9884220 Feb 15 10:27 go  
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 bryan  staff  15065500 Feb 15 10:27 godoc  
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 bryan  staff   2976976 Feb 15 10:27 gofmt
```

Comment: What do you mean by `goapp`? `go` is the application.

Comment: Not according to the Tutorial:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/getting-started/creating-guestbook

Comment: Did you just create a new tag for goapp without saying that it was? (I assume goappengine is the go sdk for developing apps to run under google's appengine).

Comment: goapp is a binary that should be installed with the Go sdk. It seems to be used to start a local server.

Comment: @BryanWheelock The Go AppEngine SDK has its own separate folder. It is not installed into the Go SDK, you won't find `goapp` in the `go/bin` folder.

Comment: Oh, so Golang  needs to be installed first AND then install the Go appengine SDK?

Comment: I ran a find on my entire systems and goapp doesn't exist there.

Comment: @BryanWheelock Go (golang) is not required for the Google App Engine SDK (as it has a bundled Go SDK). Please read my other post entirely (this is mentioned in it): [Google Go SDK or Golang app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025458/google-go-sdk-or-golang-app/39032559#39032559)

Comment: @BryanWheelock If you can't find the `goapp` binary, that means have not downloaded and / or extracted the AppEngine SDK (or not to a folder where you're looking for it).

Comment: I have a go binary, but not a goapp binary. The tutorial uses $ goapp server    to start a local GAE server.

I attempted $ go server and that didn't work either.

Comment: I just downloaded the SDK again. It has the exact same name but when I unpacked the new download it contained google_appengine and the goapp binary.   I wish I understood why it was different from the content of my earlier download.

Comment: `-rw-r--r--@   1 bryan  staff  68629396 Feb 15 12:32 go_appengine_sdk_darwin_amd64-1.9.48 (1).zip  
-rw-r--r--@   1 bryan  staff  68629396 Feb 15 10:17 go_appengine_sdk_darwin_amd64-1.9.48.zip`

Comment: Simply extracting the AppEngine Go SDK and adding its directory to your `PATH` will allow you to use `goapp` wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Foreword:** If you are unsure what the *"Go SDK"* and the *"Google App Engine SDK for Go"* are or which one you need, I recommend you this post: [Google Go SDK or Golang app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025458/google-go-sdk-or-golang-app/39032559#39032559)

---

**Edit:** Below answer uses the Linux 64-bit version, but I also tried the OS-X 64-bit version and it's the same.

The Go AppEngine SDK has its own separate folder. It is not installed into the Go SDK, you won't find `goapp` in the `go/bin` folder.

When you unzip the Go AppEngine SDK zip file, it contains a `go_appengine` folder, and the `goapp` executable binary is right inside that along with `godoc` and `gofmt`.

E.g.:

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/go_appengine_sdk_linux_amd64-1.9.48.zip
unzip go_appengine_sdk_linux_amd64-1.9.48.zip
ll
```

Output after unpacking:

```
total 67224
drwxrwxr-x  3 myuser mygroup     4096 Feb 15 15:37 ./
drwxr-x--- 12 myuser mygroup     4096 Feb  7 00:10 ../
drwxr-xr-x  8 myuser mygroup     4096 Nov 29 19:29 go_appengine/
-rw-rw-r--  1 myuser mygroup 68822758 Dec  1 19:31 go_appengine_sdk_linux_amd64-1.9.48.zip
```

Listing contents of `go_appengine/`:

```
ll go_appengine
```

Output:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myuser mygroup  3127 Nov 29 19:29 appcfg.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myuser mygroup  3127 Nov 29 19:29 backends_conversion.py
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser mygroup   156 Nov 29 19:29 BUGS
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myuser mygroup  3127 Nov 29 19:29 bulkload_client.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myuser mygroup  3127 Nov 29 19:29 bulkloader.py
drwxr-xr-x 11 myuser mygroup  4096 Nov 29 19:29 demos
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myuser mygroup  2344 Nov 29 19:29 dev_appserver.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myuser mygroup  3127 Nov 29 19:29 download_appstats.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myuser mygroup  3127 Nov 29 19:29 endpointscfg.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myuser mygroup  1527 Nov 29 19:29 goapp
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myuser mygroup  1527 Nov 29 19:29 godoc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myuser mygroup  1527 Nov 29 19:29 gofmt
drwxr-xr-x  6 myuser mygroup  4096 Nov 29 19:29 google
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser mygroup  4096 Nov 29 19:29 gopath
drwxr-xr-x  6 myuser mygroup  4096 Nov 29 19:29 goroot
drwxr-xr-x 47 myuser mygroup  4096 Nov 29 19:29 lib
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser mygroup  5949 Nov 29 19:29 LICENSE
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myuser mygroup  2344 Nov 29 19:29 php_cli.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myuser mygroup  2344 Nov 29 19:29 _python_runtime.py
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser mygroup 17738 Nov 29 19:29 RELEASE_NOTES
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser mygroup   138 Nov 29 19:29 RELEASE_NOTES.python
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myuser mygroup  2115 Nov 29 19:29 run_tests.py
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser mygroup  4096 Nov 29 19:29 tools
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser mygroup   221 Nov 29 19:29 VERSION
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myuser mygroup 11323 Nov 29 19:29 wrapper_util.py
```

Comment: I'm running osX and downloaded go_appengine_sdk_darwin_amd64-1.9.48.zip  which is a different package. Maybe the download package does not contain all the required files.

Comment: @BryanWheelock No, I just checked it with the OS-X version, and it's the same.